# jquery loop click event doesn't work with eq(i)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add click event to 6 buttons which gonna toggle slide 6 different contents (in order).
So basically I click on button 1 and the content 1 will slide up/down etc.
I created code below which works but I don not know how to loop it to makes it simpler and works.

**WORKING CODE WITHOUT LOOP:**

```
var dropdownButtons = $('div[class*="_dropdown_but"]');
var dropdownContents = $('div[class*="_dropdown_content"]');


dropdownButtons.eq(0).click(function() {
    dropdownContents.eq(0).slideToggle();
});

dropdownButtons.eq(1).click(function() {
    dropdownContents.eq(1).slideToggle();
});

dropdownButtons.eq(2).click(function() {
    dropdownContents.eq(2).slideToggle();
});

dropdownButtons.eq(3).click(function() {
    dropdownContents.eq(3).slideToggle();
});

dropdownButtons.eq(4).click(function() {
    dropdownContents.eq(4).slideToggle();
});

dropdownButtons.eq(5).click(function() {
    dropdownContents.eq(5).slideToggle();
});
```

I tried to use FOR loop but it doesn't work and non error shows up.

**NOT WORKING LOOP I CREATED:**

```
for (i = 0; i < dropdownButtons.length; i++) {
        dropdownButtons.eq(i).click(function() {
        dropdownContents.eq(i).slideToggle();
    });
}
```

I've tried to write "eq(i)" in a different way like "eq( + i + )" or "eq( + 'i' + )" or "eq(' + i + ')" but nothing changed.

Comment: Is `_dropdown_content` near to  `_dropdown_but` ? I mean is there any positional relation, because in that case you would not event need the loop. Showing your html structure  can help us know that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you declare a variable in JavaScript, the variables are scoped to `function` they are created in or if they are in outside of `function`, they exist in the global scope.

When you create a `function`, the function inherits the variables from the `parent` scope.

When you create a `function` inside of a `for` loop, the function will inherit the `i` from the parent scope and by the time you click on any of the dropdown buttons, `i` would have incremented to `dropdownButtons.length`.

To counter this problem with `i`, you should add `let` before declaring `i` which would make `i` scoped to the `for` block instead of `global` scope. Any function that inherits `i` will have a copy of `i` instead of the original `i`. [Read more about let here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)

```
for (let i = 0; i < dropdownButtons.length; i++) {
    dropdownButtons.eq(i).click(function() {
        dropdownContents.eq(i).slideToggle();
    });
}
```